# Pyinstaller module itk has no attribute

Tags: python, pyinstaller

When I package my program with pyinstaller it gives the following error and I can't solve it.
This is the error: AttributeError: module 'itk' has no attribute 'Image' and AttributeError: module 'itk' has no attribute 'GDCMSeriesFileNames'

This is my spec file:

````
hiddenimports += collect_submodules('vtkmodules')
hiddenimports += collect_submodules('pydicom')
hiddenimports += collect_submodules('itk')

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(
['app.py'],
pathex=[],
binaries=[],
datas=[],
hiddenimports=hiddenimports,
hookspath=[],
hooksconfig={},
runtime_hooks=[],
excludes=['FixTk', 'tcl', 'tk', '_tkinter', 'tkinter', 'Tkinter'],
win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
win_private_assemblies=False,
cipher=block_cipher,
noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
pyz,
a.scripts,
[],
exclude_binaries=True,
name='app',
debug=False,
bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
strip=False,
upx=True,
console=True,
disable_windowed_traceback=False,
argv_emulation=False,
target_arch=None,
codesign_identity=None,
entitlements_file=None,
)
coll = COLLECT(
exe,
a.binaries,
a.zipfiles,
a.datas,
strip=False,
upx=True,
upx_exclude=[],
name='app',
)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solves it

````
hiddenimports = []
datas = []

hiddenimports += collect_submodules('vtkmodules')
hiddenimports += collect_submodules('pydicom')
hiddenimports += collect_submodules('itk')

datas += collect_data_files('itk', include_py_files=True)

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['app.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=datas,
    hiddenimports=hiddenimports,
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)```
````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).